# Display End Date from Start Date and Duration using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have a start date for Event like 13 October, 2016 - 18:30 and the event duration like 4 days. I want it to display inside a `DIV` like 13-16 October, 2016 using jquery and if the duration is only one day it will display only 13 October, 2016.

Is it possible to do it with jQuery. please help

Comment: Yes this is possible. Show us what you have tried so far. After that we can help you. :)

Comment: It is possible. But can you explain me in brief? When event was created the date is stored in the database or directly you display the date using jquery ?

Comment: the start date was stored in the database with the duration. im using this http://halobook.vn/tiva-events-calendar/ but i want to display the event detail page differently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this  [DEMO LINK HERE https://jsfiddle.net/zytz3e9p/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/zytz3e9p/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="startDate"></div>
<div class="eventDuration"></div>
```

JS (using jquery)-

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];

  var eventDate = '28 October, 2016 - 18:30';   
  eventDate = eventDate.split('-')[0];
  var eventDuration = 2;

    var eDate = new Date(eventDate);
  var sDate =new Date(eventDate); 

  sDate.setDate(eDate.getDate() + eventDuration -1);
  console.log(sDate);

  var startDate = eDate.getDate();
  var endDate = sDate.getDate(); 


  var text=''
  if(eventDuration == 1){
     text = startDate+' '+ monthNames[eDate.getMonth()]+',    '+eDate.getFullYear();
  }
  else if(sDate.getMonth() != eDate.getMonth() && sDate.getFullYear() == eDate.getFullYear())
  {
  text = startDate+' '+ monthNames[eDate.getMonth()]+" - "+endDate+' '+ monthNames[sDate.getMonth()]+',       '+eDate.getFullYear();
  }
   else if(sDate.getFullYear() != eDate.getFullYear())
  {
  text = startDate+' '+ monthNames[eDate.getMonth()]+',       '+eDate.getFullYear()+" - "+endDate+' '+ monthNames[sDate.getMonth()]+',    '+sDate.getFullYear();
  }
  else{
   text = startDate+"-"+endDate+' '+ monthNames[eDate.getMonth()]+',      '+eDate.getFullYear();
  }
  $(".startDate").text("Start Date: "+ eventDate);
   $(".eventDuration").text("Duration: "+text);

});
```

Comment: It doesn't work correctly when the end date is after the end of the month (for example if start is 28 Oct, and duration is 7 days): https://jsfiddle.net/zytz3e9p/

Comment: Then whats your output format? i will update code based on your output.

Comment: Actually output was : 13-16 October, 2016 . What will be the output formate for two months?

Comment: Please check this https://jsfiddle.net/zytz3e9p/1/ . you can update your output format. @Teoulas